# Extracting data from String using Java Regex

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a string 
"     11:45 AM,      12:30 PM,     04:50 PM     "

I wish to extract the first time from this string using java regex.

I have created a java regex like :

"\d*\S\d*\s(AM|PM)"  for this.

However i can only match this pattern in Java rather than extract it. How can i extract the first token using the Regex i created

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The capturing parentheses where missing. Here is the code sample that should help you.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\d*):(\d*)\s(AM|PM)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
if (m.find()) {
    String hours = m.group(1);
    String minutes = m.group(2);
}
```

Comment: Rewritten as :

Pattern p= Pattern.compile("(\\d*):(\\d*)\\s(AM|PM)");

            Matcher m = p.matcher(ShowTime[i]);
            
            if(m.find())
            {
              String hours = m.group(1);
              String minutes = m.group(2);
              String timeFormat = m.group(3);
              String finalTime= hours+":"+minutes+" "+timeFormat;
            }

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to extract the first time, you can use the parse method of SimpleDateFormat directly, like this:

```
    String testString = " 11:45 AM, 12:30 PM, 04:50 PM ";

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa");
    Date parsedDate = sdf.parse(testString);

    System.out.println(parsedDate);
```

From the api, the partse method: "Parses text from the beginning of the given string to produce a date", so it will ignore the other two dates.

Regarding the pattern:

```
hh --> hours in am/pm (1-12)
mm --> minutes
aa --> AM/PM marker
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry could not try your solution. Thanks for Helping

Comment: Don't worry about that, maybe you'll get to use it in the future :)